# React Native (Expo) Issue with addEventListener for Deep Link Response

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, deep-linking

**Description:**
I'm working on a React Native application using Expo, and I'm facing an issue with the addEventListener method not working as expected. Specifically, I'm using it to listen for deep link responses, but I'm not receiving the expected response.

**Code:**

```
**export default function App() {
  const openPaymentApp = async (payApp) => {
    let url = "";
    switch (payApp) {
      case "PAYTM":
        url = "paytmmp://";
        break;
      case "GPAY":
        url = "tez://upi/";
        break;
      case "PHONEPE":
        url = "phonepe://";
        break;
    }
    url =
      url +
     "pay?pa=merchant@bank&pn=Company&mc=0000&tr=123456789ABCDEFG&tn=Product&am=100&cu=INR";
    console.log("URL : ", url);
    try {
      await Linking.openURL(url);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("ERROR : ", err);
    }
  };

  const handleDeepLink = async (event) => {
    console.log(event.url); // This line is not called
    if (event.url.startsWith("exp://192.168.1.9:8081")) {
      try {
       //handle response
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error processing payment callback:", error);
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    Linking.addEventListener("url", handleDeepLink);
  }, []);


  return (
    <View style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center", flex: 1 }}>
      <Button
        color="#00B9F1"
        title="PAYTM"
        onPress={() => openPaymentApp("PAYTM")}
      />
      <Button
        color="#6739b7"
        title="PHONE PE"
        onPress={() => openPaymentApp("PHONEPE")}
      />
      <Button
        color="#F59E0B"
        title="GPAY"
        onPress={() => openPaymentApp("GPAY")}
      />
    </View>
  );
}**
```

**Problem:**
I've set up the handleDeepLink function to handle deep link responses, but it's not being triggered when a deep link event occurs. As a result, I'm unable to extract the payment status from the deep link URL and display the corresponding alert.

**Expected Behavior:**
When a deep link URL with the pattern "exp://192.168.1.9:8081" is received, the handleDeepLink function should extract the payment status from the URL and show an alert accordingly.

**Actual Behavior:**
The handleDeepLink function doesn't seem to be triggered or is not handling the deep link URLs as expected. Therefore, I'm not receiving the payment status logs.

**What I've Tried:**

1. Verified that the deep link URL format matches the expected pattern.
2. Checked that the useEffect hook is correctly adding the event listener for deep linking events.

**Question:**

- What could be causing the addEventListener method not to work as expected in my React Native (Expo) application?
- Are there any potential issues in the code that I may have overlooked?
- Are there any additional steps or best practices I should follow when working with deep linking in React Native (Expo)?

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and fix this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!